# Redim Preserve 2D array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have some code, which takes values from range and put them in an array. So I have 1,000,000 rows and 4 columns.

```
x= Range("A1:D1000000").value

ReDim Arr(0 To UBound(x, 1), 0 To 4)

for i = 1 to 10
  for y = 1 to 4
    Arr(i - 1, y-1 ) = x(i, y)
  next y
next i

ReDim Preserve ARR(i)

Listbox1.list = Arr
```

I have tried

```
ReDim Preserve ARR(i)
ReDim Preserve ARR(i,4)
ReDim Preserve ARR(1,i)
```

Without Redim Preserve I get all 1.000.000 result with blanks

How to resize preserve to i size so I get result only 10 result?

Comment: There's a few ways you can do this but one problem is that you can only resize the *last* dimension of a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: The correct size should be `ReDim Arr(1 To UBound(x, 1), 1 To 4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x= Range("A1:D1000000").value

ReDim Arr( 0 To 4 , 0 To UBound(x, 1))

for i = 1 to 10
  for y = 1 to 4
    Arr( y-1, i - 1 ) = x(i, y)
  next y
next i

ReDim Preserve ARR(0 to 4, 0 to i)
```

and  instead of:

```
Listbox1.List = Arr
```

you should use:

```
Listbox1.column = Arr
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to restructure your code a little bit. You can only resize the *last* dimension of a multidimensional array.

What I would probably do unless there is a compelling reason to do otherwise, is to simply resize the Range object you're working with. This is easier than trying to resize the array.

```
Sub Test()
Dim x As Variant, ARR As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim y As Integer

Dim rng As Range  'Declare a range object we will use later

' Assign to our range object
Set rng = Range("A1:D1000000") 

'Resize your range object, it is easier to do this than to resize an array
Set rng = rng.Resize(10, 4)

'Now, your array x will take on the desired size of the range
'assign the rng.Value to array "x"
x = rng.Value

'And the array ARR will also take on this property based on x.
ReDim ARR(0 To UBound(x, 1), 0 To 4)

For i = 1 To 10
  For y = 1 To 4
    ARR(i - 1, y - 1) = x(i, y)
  Next y
Next i

End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

If you need to maintain the dimensions of your Range object, then you could do this instead, which will make `x` an appropriately sized array, **without** resizing the range object itself.

```
' Assign to our range object
    Set rng = Range("A1:D1000000") 

'Use the resize method when assigning to array "x":
x = rng.Resize(10, 4).Value
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i need resize dinamicly, so "for i = 1 to DynamicValue"

Comment: OK well that was not really clear from your question, in that case, the other accepted answer will be what I meant by "restructuring your code".  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't read in all million rows. Find the last row of your range that contains data and only bring that data in.

```
Sub FillLb()

    Dim vaRange As Variant
    Dim aList() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim rLastCell As Range

    Sheet1.ListBox1.Clear

    'Find the last cell that has something ("*") in it by searching
    'backward from A1 using xlPrevious
    Set rLastCell = Sheet1.Range("A1:D1000000").Find("*", Sheet1.Range("A1"), xlValues, , , xlPrevious)

    'Only read in up to the last value
    vaRange = Sheet1.Range("A1", rLastCell).Value
    ReDim aList(0 To UBound(vaRange, 1) - 1, 0 To UBound(vaRange, 2) - 1)
    Sheet1.ListBox1.ColumnCount = UBound(vaRange, 2)

    For i = LBound(vaRange, 1) To UBound(vaRange, 1)
        For j = LBound(vaRange, 2) To UBound(vaRange, 2)
            aList(i - 1, j - 1) = vaRange(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

    Sheet1.ListBox1.List = aList

End Sub
```